# Raspberry Pi 3 B apt-get update

Tags: networking, pip, raspberry-pi3, debian-jessie

I use raspberry pi 3b jessie distribution.
I am trying to update my raspberry but it gives me this error:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org jessie InRelease 100% [1 InRelease
>   gpgv 6,893 B]Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.r
>   Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jessie InRelease data and signature
>   failed E: GPG error: http://archive.raspbian.org jessie InRelease:
>   Clearsigned file isn
>   't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

And also when I tried to download python packages through pip, it shows:

> sudo pip install 'pyglet' 
>   Downloading/unpacking pyglet   Cannot fetch
>   index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/   Could not find any
>   downloads that satisfy the requirement pyglet Cleaning up... No
>   distributions at all found for pyglet Storing debug log for failure in
>   /root/.pip/pip.log.

Could somebody please point me out where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your internet provider is running a 'transparent proxy' that is interfering with apt-get

https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication

Comment: I have tried with another internet provider, but still same.Could i somehow bypass this? Or alternative methods?

Comment: I even used http://whatismyip.network/proxy-check-tool-detect-how-isp-transparent/ and said that the provider does'nt use transparent proxy